# Can type libraries generated with microsoft office 2010 work on a machine with office 2013 installed?

Tags: com, ms-office, ole

I have a Visual c++ application that uses imports on the office COM components to manipulate office documents.The app relies on the installed office version on the users' machine.The example below is a  section of a type library header that I have generated for excel from my installed office version(2010):

```
 // Created by Microsoft (R) C/C++ Compiler Version 10.00.40219.01 (e8ba858a).
//
// d:\play_ground\pimawordtopdf\release\excel.tlh
//
// C++ source equivalent of Win32 type library C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft      Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.EXE
// compiler-generated file created 11/26/14 at 09:02:55 - DO NOT EDIT!

//
// Cross-referenced type libraries:
//
//

#pragma once
```

This is working great on my other test machine with office 2007 installed but some things fail to work properly on a machine with office 2013 . My question is: are type libraries for microsoft office backward compatible so that those generated with 2010 work for 2007 .If this is true I would have to generate 2013 type libraries and compile my app with them so it works on 2013 ,2010 and 2007 .

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's not a type library, just the .tlh file that was auto-generated *from* the type library.  Along with the .tli file (auto-generated wrapper functions), it makes COM programming a lot easier.  The COM object automation model has been compatible for well over 16 years.  Quite a feat, but cracks are starting to develop.  And of course it is *backwards* compatibility, you can't expect an interface method that was added in 2010 to work on 2007.  You can only get a helpful answer if you document your *specific* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, type libraries are backward compatible until you use only types available in all Office versions, not new members from the latest versions. You will get an exception if you try to call a member which is missed in the old Office version. That's why I'd suggest using the oldest type library, for example, for Office 2007 if it is the min supported version. If required, at runtime you can check the Office version, and if the code is run against the newest version, you may call new members.

> but some things fail to work properly on a machine with office 2013

Could you please be more specific? Did you try to debug the code? Do you get any exceptions?

Finally, you may find the [Office Automation Using Visual C++](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/196776) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They should, but they don't. It's Microsoft we're talk about, so they can do whatever the heck they want.
They did break that COM interface and it's no longer backward compatible. 
For example, if you're using `Shapes.AddMediaObject`, then you're in trouble because it's deprecated `Shapes.AddMediaObject2`.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744080.aspx